# Better option than `shared_ptr` for "widget" tree structure?

Tags: c++

What is the best way to maintain a tree of "widgets" in modern C++? Currently, I am using a `vector` of `shared_ptr` for the child nodes, and a plain pointer to the parent node. It is used like this:

```
auto canvas = make_shared<Element>("canvas");
auto button = make_shared<Element>("button");
canvas->addChild(button);
// do something with either canvas or button
```

I am mostly satisfied, but I don't like the `make_shared<Element>` ceremony neccessary.

I also read that you [should use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6680020/143091) `unique_ptr` and have the parent element own the child elements. I agree in the general case, but if you have a "widget" tree I'm not sure how that would work. With a "widget" tree, I mean a tree like you have in e.g. GUI code. It is constructed manually by adding nodes here and there, and outside code frequently has to access individual nodes. If I'd use `unique_ptr`, the call to `addChild` would move the pointer and the above code would no longer be able to use the child object. I could make `addChild` return a regular pointer again, but that would make the call site more complicated.

Ideally, I'd just be able to say something like:

```
Element blah() {
    // this could also be changed to Element* or some_pointer<Element>,
    // but I want the call site to be clean and simple and not leak
    // implementation details
    Element canvas("canvas");
    Element button("button");
    canvas.addChild(button);
    button.manipulate();
    return canvas;
}

auto canvas = blah();
canvas.children[0].manipulate();
```

but of course this doesn't work in C++. Either `addChild` makes a copy, but then I manipulate the wrong button instance in "blah". Or it takes a pointer, but then it becomes dangling and the manipulation fails. I would need a magic operation that moves ownership of `button` to `canvas` and replaces `button` with a husk object that points to the real button. For that, I'd have to replace Element with a kind of smart container that fakes reference semantics, and hide the real object inside (I think C++/WinRT does something like that). However, this seems very unidiomatic, and that's why I went for `shared_ptr`. Is there any other idiom I am missing?

Comment: Why are you making a mountain out of a mole hill just because you do not like `make_shared<Element>`?

Comment: @EdHeal: I see there are different patterns I can use in this case, and I would like to learn about the benefits and drawbacks of each. This is what I came up with, however I read that some people advise against using `shared_ptr` in this way. Maybe it is fine, maybe there is a better way. I'm not "making a mountain out of a mole hill". There is no huge problem, I am not complaining, just trying to learn something and to improve my craft.

Comment: I think smart pointers are just the wrong approach to begin with if you need such explicit control over your objects' lifetime. I'd just use a `std::vector<Element*> children`, prevent copying, make sure to keep the `delete`s well encapsulated in `Element`'s destructor and make sure that every `Element` must be constructed with a `Parent` pointer argument. I would also not provide an `addChild`; there should never be an `Element` not attached to a parent, not even briefly.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: The thing is, I don't need *explicit* control of the object's lifetimes. The less I have to worry about lifetimes, the better. I'd like to avoid having dangling or invalid pointers as much as possible. What I do need is the ability to have unattached Elements, or to detach a subtree, use it, and attach it later somewhere else. Think of DOM nodes. If that were not the case, I would go with your approach.

Comment: It could be instructive to look at how Qt deal with this.

Comment: @jdm: I don't know, but *"detach a subtree, use it, and attach it later somewhere else"* sounds pretty much like explicit control to me.

Comment: @ChristianHackl: The user of this class shouldn't have to bother about allocations or ownership or lifetimes. You get an item from somewhere, do some operations with it, maybe attach it as a child to another item, and pass it on. In that sense, I would say it lifetime management is completely implicit. Allocation happens internally, e.g. by using shared pointers.

Answer (score 1):

You could make `addChild` behave like an `emplace` method and have it create a `unique_ptr` internally and then return a non-owning pointer (or reference). I.e. something like:

```
template <class... Args>
Element & Element::addChild (Args && ... args) {
  children_.push_back(std::make_unique<Element>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
  return children_.back();
}
```

So now you can do the following without exposing any of the pointer-stuff at the call site:

```
Element blah () {
  Element canvas("canvas");
  Element & button = canvas.addChild("button");
  button.manipulate();
  return canvas;
}
```

**Edit:** Made example `addChild` code more concise.